# Software that generates some JUnit code

Tags: java, junit

I'd like a program that generates some JUnits for me. Not necessarily the full JUnit but at least more of a start. I work for a company that believes in near 100% JUnit code coverage. If I add an accessor or a mutator, not testing this counts against me. Having private fields requires me to use reflection to set private properties to some mocked value. I can do this, but it's time consuming and I wish there was some tool to help with this. I tried randoop but couldn't get it do generate anything and it was very hard to use. As you might expect though, the company is not willing to pay for software to do this. Can anyone recommend a something that can take some code and generate suggested JUnit code?

Comment: An example of exactly what you'd like the code generation to do would be helpful.

Comment: Which IDE you using? There was some plugin for Eclipse. I think the name was JUnit-Tools.